# typesafe config - prefer empty value over fallback

Tags: scala, typesafe-config

having config A:

```scala
akka {
  cluster {} //empty
}
```

and config B:

```scala
akka {
  cluster { some = thing } //non empty
}
```

I would like to get `akka.cluster = empty` - taken from first object A when merging them, e.g.

```scala
val config = A.withFallback(B). // prefers A over B... but
```

but when merging happens, it recursively goes into the contents of A/B
and it then compares null field from A with non-null field of B
and thus returns contents of B.

Long story short: empty object does NOT take priority over non-empty object

Is there a way to make sure that empty A takes over the non-empty B?

thanks

ps: it's a simplified example. I need to merge a more complex A with a more complex B, so I am looking for a general solution

Comment: That's the intended behaviour. Have you tried by using `cluster = null` rather than empty? I don't think it would change anything but worth trying if you did not.